# @Html.TextBoxFor for repeated properties in the model

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, loops, view

Please help me solve this problem. I am currently trying to do this in MVC3, VB.NET.

Consider the following model:

```
Public Class SampleData
    Public Property PTY_1 as String
    Public Property PTY_2 as String
    Public Property PTY_3 as String
    '...snipped
    Public Property PTY_19 as String
    Public Property PTY_20 as String
End Class
```

Currently in my view, I have the following code:

```
<tr><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.PTY_1)</td></tr>
<tr><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.PTY_2)</td></tr>
<tr><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.PTY_3)</td></tr>
'...snipped
<tr><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.PTY_19)</td></tr>
<tr><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.PTY_20)</td></tr>
```

As you can see, this will require 20 lines of code in my view. Is there a way to use a for-loop instead so that my view has fewer lines? Thanks.

---

**Update 1.** I have tried adding a new property PTY to my model to access the properties based on an index. Thus PTY(2) = PTY_2.

```
Public Class SampleData
    Public Property PTY(index as Integer) as String
        Get
            Select Case index
                Case 1 : Return PTY_1
                Case 2 : Return PTY_2
                Case 3 : Return PTY_3
                '...snipped
                Case 19 : Return PTY_19
                Case 20 : Return PTY_20
                Case Else : Return ""
            End Select
        End Get
        Set (value as String)
            Select case index
                Case 1 : PTY_1 = value
                Case 2 : PTY_2 = value
                Case 3 : PTY_3 = value
                '...snipped
                Case 19 : PTY_19 = value
                Case 20 : PTY_20 = value
            End Select
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And as for the view, I have tried the following code:

```
@For index as Integer = 1 to 20
    <tr><td>@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.PTY(index))</td></tr>
End For
```

However when I load the view, I am getting an InvalidOperationException: "Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions." T_T

Answer (score 1):

You could decorate your properties with the `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` attribute and in your view:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and if you want you could customize the template by using the `[UIHint]` attribute:

```
<DataType(DataType.MultilineText)> _
<UIHint("CustomTextArea")> _
Public Property PTY_1 as String

...
```

and then define an editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CustomTextArea.cshtml`):

```
<tr><td>@Html.TextArea("")</td></tr>
```

Comment: Hmmm... I am not sure what will happen if I decorate these properties with the MultilineText attribute. I wonder if that is applicable. 

Actually, in my real world application I have lots of properties in the model, let's say PTY_A_1 to PTY_A_20, then PTY_B_1 to PTY_B_20, up to PTY_Q_1 to PTY_Q_20. Furthermore, in my view, they will not be displayed in a linear fashion, but as columns in an html table. so PTY_A will be one column, up to PTY_Q... then the numbers (1 to 20) will be the rows...

Comment: @json, you should very strongly consider using arrays in this case instead of cluttering your model with hundredths of properties like this. Then use editor templates.

Answer (score 0):

The matter is PTY_1 to PTY_20 is the names of your future inputs.
I write in C# :)

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    string name = "PTY_" + i;
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="@name" /></td></tr>
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Your solution involves using the input tag in html, but what I need is code that uses TextBoxFor HTML Helper. Using the input tag is of course a solution, but I was wondering if the same is possible using Html.TextBoxFor. Thanks!

Comment: ugh. seriously? use an editor template, you can't afford to have code soup like this in your views.